# Diagram overlapping other layers

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity, diagram

[image]I have a a diagram and have put it as the last layer in my project file, however it overlaps with my top layer.

Is there any way to make the diagrams underneath the other layers?

I can add a picture if my explanation lacked.

Edit- I am trying to get the black features, stars/circls/triangles above the population bubbles

Comment: Please add a picture

Comment: Did you try ordering the layers through the [Layer Order Panel](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#working-with-the-legend-independent-layer-order)?

Comment: Just tried the layer order pane, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=diagrams:

> The placement of the diagrams can interact with the labeling, so you
>   can detect and solve position conflicts between diagrams and labels by
>   setting the Priority slider or the z-index value.

which indicates that diagrams are rendered with labels, and thus always over symbols.
It would therefore not be possible to do what you want. Your best solution would be to play with the placement of your diagrams and symbols (data defined might help).
Cheers,

Comment: Thankyou, no one else in the office was aware of a way either. At least we are aware now